# Difference between "this very" and "this particular"

Tags: meaning, differences

It came to my attention lately that I've read multiple authors using the expression "this very" like:

- I will be writing on this very blog
- I recommend going to this very restaurant

What's the value of using "very" in these sentences and what is the difference if we replaced "very" with "particular"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *very* is used as an adjective to emphasize what you're talking about in particular and that you're not referring to something else. Another synonym is *actual*.

> He had been saying those very words for weeks.

*Particular* can also be used in this sense. You cannot replace *very* with *particular* in every case but in your examples it's possible without changing the sentences' meaning, since *very* emphasizes that you're referring to a particular known thing [e.g., it has been mentioned before].

Answer (score 4):

You use "particular" when you want to emphasize on the "type/nature" of the subject you are referring to whereas "very" doesn't emphasize on any specific type of the subject, it depicts your strong emotion towards a particular thing..

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I think 'strong emotion towards a particular thing' got to me clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure if "very" involves a strong emotion, but it's certainly true that "particular" relates to the type/nature of the object or something else that is different about the object, and "very" doesn't imply a difference (it could just refer to the specific object you are holding - "There are millions of coins in the world but I shall show you something with this very coin.").